# Stack corrupted array/ Segmentation fault? in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

This is a simple code that wants me to search for pairs of integers that add up to the target value, but I don't see what's wrong with it. Please help?!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int sortedarr[20], targetsum, mysum, i=0, k=19, count=0; /* Declaring variables */

    printf("\nEnter target value sum: ");
    scanf("%d", &targetsum);
    printf("Enter sorted array: ");
    scanf("%s", &sortedarr[20]);

    while(k>i) {
        mysum=sortedarr[k]+sortedarr[i];

        if(mysum==targetsum) {
            printf("(%d, %d)", sortedarr[i], sortedarr[k]);
            i++;
            k+=-1;
            count++;
        }
        else if(mysum>targetsum)
            k+=-1;
        else if(mysum<targetsum)
            i++;
    }

    if(count==0)
        printf("No pairs of integers");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &sortedarr[20]);` will cause segmentation fault.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &sortedarr[20]);` <- this does not do what you think it does.

Comment: I thought so to, but I don't know how else to input an array

Comment: @a20365354.. that one is also wrong. Correct approach to input an array of integers is through a loop. Each element is input through `scanf("%d",&sortedarr[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%s", &sortedarr[20])` tries to read a *string* into `sortedarr`, starting at the *last* element. As soon as your user enters more than `sizeof(int)` characters, this can cause a segmentation fault.

What you want to do is something like:

```c
for (c=0; c < 20; c++) {
  scanf("%d", &sortedarr[c]);
}
```

Comment: Souldn't it be 4 characters instead of 1? As `int` is mostly 4 bytes.

Comment: You know, I tried this before but for some reason it didn't work. Maybe because I had ten minutes to do it only but now that I try it again it worked, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

scanf("%s", &sortedarr[20]);

This writes beyond the end of the array and probably corrupts targetsum.
In the prior answer this bug is avoided while the loop just runs up to 19.

So this statement is false:
"d a string into sortedarr, starting at the last element. "

The array is accessed "after" the last element. And that may or may not corrupt anything. It's unfefined. So everything can and will happen.